# Why are some keys harder to press than others on a new laptop I purchased?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I got a new laptop and I feel that the keys <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> under <kbd>x</kbd> are kinda stiff and louder to press than the other keys. It is an intermittent problem though.

I never had this when I had new laptops in the past. Do some laptops keyboards get better over time or should I just return this? It is odd how the stiffer keys are close together too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has a refurbished laptop been sold to me as new?](https://superuser.com/questions/1598816/has-a-refurbished-laptop-been-sold-to-me-as-new) This all sounds like a crappy situation, but the reality is this question and the other question are effectively the same question. Just return it. And if I were you I would just ask for a full refund and buy a laptop from another source.

Comment: Strange thing is, it is one of the biggest retailers in the UK and they have potentially sold me a refurb and pretended it is new.

Comment: @Coden “Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity." Which means for all you know, Curry’s is not at fault but rather their distributor. Meaning they could have received a dozen of new laptops, but at the distributor someone accidentally place a  refurb into the mix. Or maybe even a return in the same box? I would simply return it and be 100% honest that this is not a new laptop. Don’t place blame on Curry’s or staff. But state the clear facts and move on from it.

Comment: It had unopened warranty card, the seals were unbroken on the packaging and all the dust covers were re inserted etc.. this was not a case of confusing it with a return. There has been clear effort to pass it off as new but it wasn't quite good enough.

Comment: “There has been clear effort to pass it off as new but it wasn't quite good enough.” Where would that have happened? The distributor? The manufacturer? Don’t blame the messenger or the seller. Mistakes happen. Just return it.